# Retrieve total amounts of rows containing strings

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in MySQL, with 5(sort of) possible values in the column 'type'... I say sort of because the data type is 'set' and 1 type has a subcategory... It's for a type of property, so the possible types are retail, office, hospitality, industrial, residential(multi family), residential(single family).

I'm attempting to paginate the results and I need to know how many pages each should have. So I need a query that tells me how many of each type are in the table, the user can select residential as a category, or single, multi as subcategories.

I can't figure out how to do a query that tells me how many of each there are, or how to retrieve those numbers as variables I can use to divide be items per page.

```
id | type
-----------------------    
1  | office  
2  | residential,single  
3  | industrial  
4  | residential,multi  
5  | retail  
6  | office  
7  | hospitality  
8  | residential,single
```

etc....

so if this was the data, I would need to get:

```
$office = 2  
$residential = 3  
$industrial = 1  
$single = 2
```

etc...

Comment: You can use MySQL's aggregate `COUNT()` function.

Comment: it will be easier if you add another field (subcategory)

Comment: Thanks, I can do a set of queries with count if there is a single type, I guess I'm wondering if there's a single query that would give me the total of each. That's where I'm really struggling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array_count_values()` function

Check the link http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

From their website http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php;

and Try this code

```
<?php

$query= // Run your select query. 
$result=  mysqli_query($link, $query);
//Run the while loop
        while($row=  mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $array[]=$row['Column_Name'];//Store the result in array 
        }

$count = array_count_values($array);//Use array count 

print_r($count);//See the result
```

**Or if you see The out put the way you want**

Run Foreach loop on the `$count` array

```
foreach($count as $key => $value) {
    //Get the out put From new array
    echo $value .'  '. $key.'<br/>' ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A count and group by should do the trick;

```
SELECT id, type, COUNT(*) as count
FROM mytable
GROUP By id
```